# Comparison between my formula and the number 1

Tags: real-analysis, inequality

It is known that the real numbers $a>0$, $b>0$, and $0<\theta<1$, then is the following inequality correct?
$$
\frac{a^\theta\cdot b^{1-\theta}}{\theta\cdot a+(1-\theta)\cdot b}\leq 1
$$
And why? Thanks in advance.

Comment: For a proof of this inequality and its generalization see http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1788730/72031

Comment: @ParamanandSingh Thanks for your link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $\log x$ is concave, we have
$$ \log(\theta a+(1-\theta)b)\geq \theta\log a+(1-\theta)\log b $$
for all $a,b>0$ and $\theta\in(0,1)$. Exponentiating both sides shows that
$$ \theta a+(1-\theta)b\geq a^{\theta}b^{1-\theta}$$
which is equivalent to the stated inequality.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. BTW, can you give the reference why the logarithm function is concave?

Comment: The second derivative is $-\frac{1}{x^2}$, which is negative.

Comment: OK. Yes, thanks again.